# Subquery returns more than 1 row in my code

Tags: mysql, sql

i wrote this and got the error, just started sql so I don't know what is the problem..
the database is sakila - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure.html , and the query is to find the actors name that played in the movie "AFRICAN EGG"

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name
FROM actor a
WHERE
    (SELECT actor_id
     FROM film_actor 
     WHERE
        (SELECT film_id
         FROM film
         WHERE title = "AFRICAN EGG"))
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are working.  (2) Describe what you want the query to do.  (3) Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name
    FROM actor a
    WHERE a.id = 
    (SELECT actor_id
    FROM film_actor 
    WHERE actor_id = 
    (SELECT film_id
    FROM film
    WHERE title="AFRICAN EGG")) you are missing each table id's. try like this.

Comment: If the table has relation ship use table join query. It will tell you why duplication occurred.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Which of these subqueries returns more than one row? What have you tried to check **why** this happens?

Comment: Table structure would help.

Comment: Your where clauses do not make sense. Since there is no in operator anywhere therefore the expression is likely to be interpreted as boolean, but the subqueries return more than 1 records.

Comment: Don't you need some sort of equality check in your WHERE clause? So instead of `WHERE (SELECT ...` should it not be `WHERE film_id = (SELECT ...`?

Comment: @Shadow ok, so where do i put the IN operator?

Comment: @jarlh sorry didn't notice the tags, they removed

Comment: @Shadow: actually any self-respecting DBMS would flat out refuse to run that query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a comparison in your where statements

```sql
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name
FROM actor a
WHERE a.actor_id in      -- probably actor id
    (SELECT actor_id
     FROM film_actor 
     WHERE film_id in    -- probably film id
        (SELECT film_id
         FROM film
         WHERE title = "AFRICAN EGG"))
```

You could also do this with joins

```sql
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name
FROM actor a join film_actor fa on
    a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
  JOIN film f ON
    fa.film_id = f.film_id
WHERE f.title = "AFRICAN EGG";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below queries based on your requirement.

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name
FROM actor a
WHERE a.id IN
    (SELECT fa.actor_id
     FROM film_actor fa
     WHERE fa.film_id IN
        (SELECT film_id
         FROM film
         WHERE title = "AFRICAN EGG"))

SELECT 
    a.first_name,
    a.last_name
FROM actor a 
JOIN film_actor fa ON fa.film_actor = a.id
JOIN film f ON f.id = fa.film_id
WHERE f.title = "AFRICAN EGG";
```